# how can i calculate the similarity between dicts values

Tags: python, levenshtein-distance

I have a list of words like this where each word have an occurrence what I want is to calculate the similarity between all the word, for example, `python` and `mypython`, they are similar so all sum the occurrence:

```
my_list = [{
      "name": "python",
      "occ": 1623
    },
    {
      "name": "C++",
      "occ": 1527
    },
    {
      "name": "programming",
      "occ": 390
    },
    {
      "name": "programme",
      "occ": 371
    },
    {
      "name": "mypython",
      "occ": 252
    },
    {
      "name": "pythonne",
      "occ": 219
    }]
```

I want to calculate the similarities between all the words of this list and sum the occurrence to have something like this

```
my_list = [{
      "name": "python",
      "occ": 2094
    },
    {
      "name": "C++",
      "occ": 1527
    },
    {
      "name": "programming",
      "occ": 761
    }]
```

I think of using the Levenshtein distance but I don't know if this will be the good choice and fastest way to do this?

```
def levenshtein(seq1, seq2):
    size_x = len(seq1) + 1
    size_y = len(seq2) + 1
    matrix = np.zeros ((size_x, size_y))
    for x in xrange(size_x):
        matrix [x, 0] = x
    for y in xrange(size_y):
        matrix [0, y] = y

    for x in xrange(1, size_x):
        for y in xrange(1, size_y):
            if seq1[x-1] == seq2[y-1]:
                matrix [x,y] = min(
                    matrix[x-1, y] + 1,
                    matrix[x-1, y-1],
                    matrix[x, y-1] + 1
                )
            else:
                matrix [x,y] = min(
                    matrix[x-1,y] + 1,
                    matrix[x-1,y-1] + 1,
                    matrix[x,y-1] + 1
                )
    print (matrix)
    return (matrix[size_x - 1, size_y - 1])
```

Comment: This question is related and discusses some options: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/12575/similarity-between-two-words

Comment: If you're familiar with NLP you could use stemming or lemmatization

Comment: thankyou for your answers, but what i can't get is how can i apply this to my list